# Why are two entries of $_POST undefined when accessed in my code while the rest are fine?

Tags: php, database

I am working on PHP and databases for an assignment and I would like some help on my coding.  The form is submitted to process.php for processing (code for both are reproduced below). I am getting an undefined index warning for `$_POST['CustomerID']` and `$_POST['BodyStyle']` when process.php runs (the exact location is noted in the code), and the information entered for these fields on the form won't get inserted or updated in the database. The other fields work as intended, generating no errors and are stored in the database. What is going wrong? How can I fix it?

### Process.php:

```
<?php

$dbname = "cars";
$dbuser = "carsuser";
$dbpass = "carspass250";

$dbconnect = odbc_connect($dbname,$dbuser, $dbpass)
or die ("Could not connect. <br>");

$opcode = (int) $_POST["opcode"];
$recno = (int) $_POST["recno"];   

if ( ($opcode < -1) || ($opcode > 1) )
    {
    echo "Invalid data passed from form! <br>";
    exit();
    }

if (($opcode == 0) || ($opcode == 1))
   {
    $CustomerID = $_POST['CustomerID'];  //Undefined Index
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $make = $_POST['make'];
    $model = $_POST['model'];
    $BodyStyle = $_POST['BodyStyle'];  //Undefined Index
    $color = $_POST['color'];

if (!all_fields_ok($CustomerID, $year, $make, $model, $BodyStyle, $color))
   {
   exit();
   }
    }

if ($opcode == -1)    
    $SqlStatement = "DELETE from Vehicle WHERE VehicleID = $recno";

if ($opcode == 0)      
   {
   $SqlStatement = "UPDATE Vehicle SET ".
    "CustomerID = '$CustomerID', ". 
    "Year = '$year',  ".
    "Make = '$make', ".
    "Model = '$model', ".
    "BodyStyle = '$BodyStyle', ". 
    "Color = '$color' ".
    "WHERE VehicleID = $recno";
    }                

if ($opcode == 1)
   {
   $SqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Vehicle ". 
     "(CustomerID, Year, Make, Model, BodyStyle, Color) ".  
     "VALUES ('$CustomerID', '$year', '$make', '$model', '$BodyStyle', '$color')";
    }

print $SqlStatement."<br>";
$recs = odbc_exec($dbconnect, $SqlStatement)
    or die ("Could not locate database");

print "Database Updated! <br>";
print "<a href=listall.php>Return to List</a> ";

function all_fields_ok($CustomerID, $year, $make, $model, $BodyStyle, $color )
   {
   $errormsg = "";
   $flag = 0;

   if ( (!is_numeric($CustomerID)) )
      {
      $errormsg = $errormsg."Input:  $CustomerID <br>";
      $errormsg = $errormsg."Only numbers are aloud <br><br>";
      $flag=1;
      } 

    if(!(is_numeric($year)) || (!(strlen($year)==4)))
      {
      $errormsg = $errormsg."Input:  $year <br>";
      $errormsg = $errormsg."Please enter a four-digit year <br><br>";
      $flag=1; 
      }

  if  ((!ctype_alpha($make))  )
      {
      $errormsg = $errormsg."Input:  $make <br>";
      $errormsg = $errormsg."Please enter the make of the vehicle, characters only<br>        <br>";
      $flag=1; 
      }

   if  (!(ctype_alnum($model)) )
      {
      $errormsg = $errormsg."Input:  $model<br>";
      $errormsg = $errormsg."Please enter the model of the vehicle, numbers and     characters aloud <br><br>";
      $flag=1; 
      }

  if ((!ctype_alpha($BodyStyle))  )
      {
      $errormsg = $errormsg."Input:  $BodyStyle <br>";
      $errormsg = $errormsg."Please enter the bodystyle of the vehicle, characters only     <br><br>";
      $flag=1;
      }

   if ((!ctype_alpha($color))  )
      {
      $errormsg = $errormsg."Input:  $color <br>";
      $errormsg = $errormsg."Please enter the color of the vehicle, characters only.     <br><br>";
      $flag=1; 
      }  

    if ($flag == 1)
        {
        echo "Data not trustworthy.  Please revise input and try again. <br><br>";
        echo $errormsg;
        return false; 
        }
    else
        return true;  
   }
?>
```

### form:

```
<?php

$dbname = "cars";
$dbuser = "carsuser";
$dbpass="carspass250";

$dbconnect = odbc_connect($dbname,$dbuser, $dbpass)
    or die ("Could not connect. <br>");

$opcode = (int) $_POST["opcode"];
$recno = (int) $_POST["recno"]; 

if ( ($opcode < -1) || ($opcode > 1) )
    {
    echo "Invalid data passed from form! <br>";
    exit();
    }

if ($opcode == 0)
   {

   $SqlStatement = "SELECT * from Vehicle WHERE VehicleID = $recno";
   $recs = odbc_exec($dbconnect, $SqlStatement)
    or die ("Could not execute query");

   $row = odbc_fetch_array($recs) ;

    $VehicleID = $row['VehicleID'];
    $CustomerID = $row['CustomerID'];
    $year = $row['Year'];
    $make = $row['Make'];
    $model = $row['Model'];
    $BodyStyle = $row['BodyStyle'];
    $color = $row['Color'];
    }
else   
   {
    $recno = 0;
    $VehicleID = 0;
    $CustomerID = "";
    $year = "";
    $make = "";
    $model = "";
    $BodyStyle = "";
    $color = "";
  }

print "<h1>Vehicle Record </h1>";
print "<form action=process.php method=post>   \n";

print "<table>";     
 if ($opcode == 0)  
        print "<tr><td> Record Number:</td><td align=left>$recno</td>   </tr>\n";  
 else
        print "<tr><td> Record Number: </td><td align=left>New Record</td>   </tr>\n";  

 print "<tr><td> Customer ID: </td>";
 print "<td> <input type=text name=CustomerID value=\"$CustomerID\"></td></tr>   \n";
 print "<tr><td> Year: </td>";
 print "<td> <input type=text name=year value=\"$year\"></td></tr>   \n";
 print "<tr><td> Make: </td>";
 print "<td> <input type=text name=make value=\"$make\"></td></tr>   \n";   
 print "<tr><td> Model: </td>";
 print "<td> <input type=text name=model value=\"$model\"></td></tr>   \n"; 
 print "<tr><td> Style: </td>";
 print "<td> <input type=text name=BodyStyle value=\"$BodyStyle\"></td></tr>   \n"; 
 print "<tr><td> Color: </td>";
 print "<td> <input type=text name=color value=\"$color\"></td></tr>   \n"; 

 print "<input type=hidden name=opcode value=$opcode>   \n";
 print "<input type=hidden name=recno value=$recno>   \n";
 print "<tr><td> <input type=submit value='Submit Record'></td><td></td></tr>   \n   \n";
print "</table>";
print "</form>";

odbc_close($dbconnect);
?>
```

Comment: It's always good to include error output, especially on homework questions. It means we can teach you how to interpret the errors, then you can learn where to look for problems.

Comment: if I wanted to do an error output for BodyStyle using an array i would use what? the 
$array = array("convertible", "coupe", "hatchback", "sedan", "suv", "truck", "van/minivan", "wagon");
is_array($BodyStyle, $array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables in your $_POST data are defined by the input name attributes, so if you say this

```
<input name="customer" ... />
<input name="style"  ... />
```

you need to look for

```
$_POST['customer']
$_POST['style']
```

so either change your POST lookups or your input names, and make them match.

Also, you should check your html standards, the attributes values should go between "" and you should close all tags with either  or finishing it with  />

Comment: I Love you! ok not really but I was looking for the error in the wrong spot not noticing that the input name was A) different and B) affected the next page. I thought it was the variables in my if/else statement

Comment: oh, come on, love me for real! at least for a couple hours! it won't do you any harm =P. Or you COULD upvote and choose my answer =)

Comment: well, tempting....ill love you for a min. and choose you as an answer since you were great help.  Now on to the next part of the assignment of having an error checking function

Answer (score 0):

you're not getting the CustomerID and the BodyStyle variables from your POST data, there's something wrong with the request (your form, or whatever you're using)

Comment: okay so its not on this page.   should I post the coding from the form im using?  why would I be able to get the other variables if I did the same thing for each one

Comment: yes, edit your question, and add the form's HTML, or even post it in a pastebin

Comment: I did and the variable names are the same on each page for whats being passed, that is why I am not understanding what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Correct this column...it cannot have space in it.

```
"Body Style = '$BodyStyle', ".
```